# Where is the variable being appended through super().append(name)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super

I am new to Python coding and there is a question I have. Here is the code:

```
class ManageContact(list):

    def addManager(self, name, number):
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise TypeError('please enter a string')

        super().append(name)\
```

It works just fine. However, I do not know where is the variable "name" being appended through super()/append(name). Could you kindly help? Thank you in advance.

I have tried running the code. It works i.e. the object is being created and the method can be run. But I do not know in which list the variable "name" is being added.

Comment: What is your base class here? Can you post the complete code?

Answer (score 1):

The `name` is being added to your `self` object, which inherits a list. So you can access it using `self[0]`, `self[1]`, etc. `print(self)` will print the entire list.

If you feel this is not intuitive, then you should consider redesigning your class. Is it better to inherit `list` directly, or would it be more clear to have a `list` member in your class? Keep in mind that now, your class has all the methods expected on a list; is that really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should move the list to beeing a variable instead of a superclass, i.e.

```py
class ManageContact(list):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.Managers: list = []

    def addManager(self, name, number) -> None:
        if not isinstance(name, str):
            raise TypeError('please enter a string')

        self.Managers.append(name)
```

The name will then be stored in `instance.Managers`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help! I realized I am making a stupid mistake. The class itself will behave as a list, hence all it's instances will also be lists (each object will be a separate list though, there's no master list). Therefore, eric.m's suggestion is way better (to declare a list variable in the class defn. instead of inheriting directly from the list class)

I am kinda new, so the silly question!

Thank you all once again.